# Histogram that's ordered by dates

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataset called `stepsperday`.

```
head(stepsperday)
```

gives

```
2012-10-01 2012-10-02 2012-10-03 2012-10-04 2012-10-05 2012-10-06 
         0        126      11352      12116      13294      15420
```

Essentially, it has data for 30 days, and I would like to make a histogram out of this.

However, using `qplot(stepsperday, geom="histogram")` gives

```
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`
```

Introducing `bins = 30` does not solve the problem, and I'm unsure to get it to work with ggplot.
Changing the dates with `names(stepsperday) <- c(1:30)` also does not do much.

How can I make a histogram where it is ordered by the day.

Comment: You want a column chart, not a histogram. See `geom_col`. A histogram summarizes the distribution of a single variable. A column chart shows the relationship between two variables, here steps and time.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example by doing `dput(stepsperday)`?

Comment: I'm really sorry, what is dput?

Comment: It's a function in base R that outputs a representation of your object that we can copy/paste to recreate that object. See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput), and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance on how to create a minimal reproducible example for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to make a column chart, not a histogram. A histogram summarizes the distribution of a single continuous variable, whereas a column chart shows the relationship between a continuous variable and a categorical one, here steps and time (days).

From the output you posted, it looks like `stepsperday` is a `zoo` object, not a column in a data frame, and `ggplot2` is designed to work with data frames (or tibbles). If that's right, then you'll want to convert it to a data frame and then generate your plot. Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

# make example zoo object to test
set.seed(123)
stepsperday <- zoo::zoo(rpois(30, lambda = 10000),
                        order.by = seq(from = lubridate::date("2020-01-01"),
                                       to = lubridate::date("2020-01-01") + 29,
                                       by = "day"))

stepsperday %>%
  # convert zoo object to data frame with date as a column
  data.frame(date = zoo::index(.), steps = .) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = steps)) +
    geom_col()
```

Here's what that produces:

[image]